# shutil.move -> WindowsError: [Error32] The process cannot access the file

Tags: python

I use Python 2.5. and have a problem with shutil.move

```
print(srcFile)
print(dstFile)
shutil.move(srcFile, dstFile)
```

Output:

```
c:\docume~1\aaa\locals~1\temp\3\tmpnw-sgp
D:\dirtest\d\c\test.txt
...
WindowsError: [Error32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by 
  another process: 'c:\\docume~1\\aaa\\locals~1\\temp\\3\\tmpnw-sgp'
```

I use it on a Windows 2003 Server.

So, what's wrong here? Does anyone know?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to continue in your script use:

```
try:
    shutil.move(srcFile, dstFile)
except WindowsError:
    pass
```

The reason your getting error 32 is because there is another process on your computer or server that is using that file. You might want to not copy temp files as they are not really important by name.